# How to get id of selected value from dropdown and use it in other dropdown in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm newbie at Laravel and on stackoverflow. I'm making an app for registration. I want to show all those ids of section where class_id is selected in upper dropdown.

```
 $cid=DB::table('classses')->get();
 $counterr=0;

  $sec=DB::table('sections')->where('class_id',$cid)->get();
  $counterrr=0;
```

Dropdown menu for **Class**

```
   <div class="col-md-6">
   <select class="" name="class_id">
         <option value="null">Class</option>
         @foreach($cid as $cc)
             @if($counterr==0)
                <option selected="selected" value="{{$cc->id}}">{{$cc->title}}</option>
                {$counterr++}}
             @else
                 <option value="{{$cc->id}}">{{$cc->title}}</option>
             @endif
        @endforeach
    </select>
```

Dropdown menu for **Section** where I want to get all the values of section where class_id is upper selected

```
       <select section="" name="section_id">
           <option value="null">Section</option>
           @foreach($sec as $sc)
               @if($counterrr==0)
                   <option selected="selected" value="{{$sc->id}}">{{$sc->title}}</option>
                   {{$counterrr++}}
               @else
                   <option value="{{$sc->id}}">{{$sc->title}}</option>
               @endif
            @endforeach
    </select>
```

Please help me in these case. You can freely ask anything if you want to.

Comment: Are both dropdowns on the same page?

Comment: Yes both are on same page

Comment: Ok that's not possible unless you use some javascript.  PHP is a server side language so once the page has loaded you cant revert back to PHP until the page reloads.  So then we have to use AJAX to call to a route that will package up the sections of the currently selected class and return as JSON.  Then from there you will need to iterate through the returned options to populate the second select box options

Comment: I've added it in my blog. May be helpful, http://stacklearning.com/php/laravel/how-to-make-a-dynamic-drop-down-based-on-value-selected-in-another-drop-down-with-laravel-and-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set a `$counter` in order to set the first select option to `selected`. Instead, you can check if the `$key == 0`:

```
<select class="" name="class_id">
    <option value="null">Class</option>
    @foreach($cid as $key => $cc)
        <option {{ $key == 0 ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }} value="{{$cc->id}}">{{$cc->title}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Here we use a **ternary** expression to echo out the selected option based on if `$key` equals `0`. If not, it will not echo out anything.